# How do validate the file name which is appended by 1 each time whenever I download the same file everytime using Selenium with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, file, fileinputstream

When i tried to download the same file the file name is appended with 1 each time. for ex:
first time the file name will b filedownload1805258.xls and for the second time filedownload1805258(1).xls and for the third time filedownload1805258(3).xls.
So now how do i validate this ?

Currently my method is:

```
public void onIVerifyIsDownloadedIn(String arg0, String arg1) throws Throwable {
    if (defaultDataJsonObject.containsKey(arg1)) {
        arg1 = defaultDataJsonObject.get(arg1).toString();
    }
    if (defaultDataJsonObject.containsKey(arg0)) {
        arg0 = defaultDataJsonObject.get(arg0).toString();
    }
    File filelocation=new File(arg1);
   File[] list= filelocation.listFiles();
    for(File file:list){
        try {
            if (file.getName().contains(arg0)) {
                Log.info("File is downloaded in given location");
                break;
            }
            else{
                Log.info("File is not downloaded.. Pleae check...!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: For a fast and easy solution just make a recursive method that checks if a file exists and increments the name/number. It should then call itself to recursively check the incremented number, this will continue until you get a number that has no match (your valid filename), and return the correct file path accordingly for ues.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this situation is to clear the directory first and then call the download method, so you will have a unique name every time.

```
void delete(File f) throws IOException {
  if (f.isDirectory()) {
    for (File c : f.listFiles())
      delete(c);
  }
  if (!f.delete())
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to delete file: " + f);
}
```